# convert character string into R integer vector

Tags: r, postgresql, vector, plr

I receive a character string "{1,0,0,0,0,0}" created as a textual representation of a vector (integer[]) by postgresql and have to cast it into a R integer/numeric vector.
Is there any efficient way to convert v into a R representation of a vector?
Thanks in advance.

> v 
>   [1] "{1,0,0,0,0,0}"
>
> class(v)
>   [1] "character"
>
> mode(v)
>   [1] "character"
>
> typeof(v)
>   [1] "character"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is positive integer then:

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit("{1,0,0,0,0}", "\\D+"))[-1])
```

If negative is a possibility:

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit("{1,-3,0,0,0}", "[,{}]"))[-1])
```